# linux file name(full path) encode

Tags: linux, file, encoding, filenames

I want to encode linux file name(full path), is there some method?
examle:
input: (the dir structure like this: )

```
/root/
/root/fileA.txt
/root/dir/
/root/dir/fileB.txt
```

after encoding: 
(just like this, human-readable is not necessary)

```
%root%
%root%fileA.txt
%root%dir%
%root%dir%fileB.txt
```

and using those new name as the new file name that I can put those files into one dir.
after like this:

```
/root1/%root%
/root1/%root%fileA.txt
/root1/%root%dir%
/root1/%root%dir%fileB.txt
```

Comment: What if your files already contain a % in their name? (And what have you tried?)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: the encoding in my example, just my first plan. It does'nt work. I tried BASE64, but i don't know if it could be as the right linux file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trick way. I used mktemp function to generate the new filename.